# Method for calculating integral of $e^{-2ix\pi\psi}/(1+x^2)$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

I am seeking the method for calculating the following integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-2ix\pi\psi}}{1+x^2} dx $$

Ideas I have are:

1) substition (however which one?)
2) integration by parts

The integral comes from the Fourier transform of $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: What is $\psi$?

Comment: $$\psi$$ comes from the Fourier transform definition - $$F(\psi)=$$ integral in question.

Comment: The integral can be calculated easily with complex methods.

Comment: @gennaromarcodevincenzis like contour integration?

Comment: Yes, and if you search for it on the site there's a high probability it's been done. The function has simple poles at $\pm i$ and it can be done with a semicircular contour, showing that the "upper" part of the integral vanishes for $R \rightarrow \infty$, where $R$ is the radius of the semicircle.

If you don't like complex methods (but you should like them, in this case I think is by far the easiest method) I'm fairly certain that cleverly inserting a parameter and differentiating under the integral sign works just as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-2ix\pi\psi}}{1+x^2} dx =\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(2\pi\psi\,x)}{1+x^2}dx-i\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(2\pi\psi\,x)}{1+x^2}dx$$
Please check [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840598/how-do-i-prove-int-infty-infty-cosxa-over-xb21dx-pi-over-e/1840800#1840800)

> $$\color{red}{I(\lambda)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\cos(\lambda x)\over
>  x^2+1}dx=\frac{\pi}{e^{\lambda}}}$$
>   and
>
> $$\color{red}{J(\lambda)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin(\lambda x)\over
>  x^2+1}dx=0}$$

Now set $\lambda=2\pi\psi$